# How to get an attribute from XML file using Java

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I have developed an **Authentication Plugin** for **Oracle Access Manager**

Briefly it contains:

- **java.class**
- the following **XML**

> I'm trying to **Dynamically** get the **`<Value>`** tag of an **`<Attribute>`** from the **XML**
>   file.

```xml
<Plugin type="Authentication">
    <author>Phill</author>
    <email>phill@example.com</email>
    <creationDate>12:47:00, 2019-07-11</creationDate>
    <description>Phill-Plugin</description>
    <configuration>
        <AttributeValuePair>
            <Attribute type="string" length="60">GenerateUrl</Attribute>
            <mandatory>true</mandatory>
            <instanceOverride>false</instanceOverride>
            <globalUIOverride>true</globalUIOverride>
            <value>This is the value i'm trying to retrieve</value>
        </AttributeValuePair>
    </configuration>
</Plugin>
```

---

> **java.class**

```java
            try {

                CredentialParam tem = context.getCredential().getParam("GenerateUrl");
                String temp = (String) tem.getValue();
                System.out.println("TEST: " + temp);
                generateUrl = temp + "The User" + user;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("\n\n\n-------------------\n");
                System.out.println("-      Input Is:         -\n");
                System.out.println("-       "+e+"            -\n");
                System.out.println("-------------------\n");
                generateUrl = "A URL" + "The User" + user;
            }
```

**Important Note:**

> The `context` object is an `AuthenticationContext` instance containing information about the **Plug-in**

Based on Oracle's **Documentation**, this is the exact way someone retrieves an `Attribute` but i'm always getting a `NullPointerException`

Is there any other way that i can retrieve the `<Value>`?

Comment: Hi, If you are looking for an attribute called "GenerateUrl" then I think you've misunderstood what an attribute actually is. You have two attributes for the 'Attribute' element : "type="string" and length="60" [Difference between attributes and elements](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_dtd_el_vs_attr.asp). If I understand your code correctly then you should be looking for the value of the 'Attribute' element (?). Apologies if it's me that is not understanding the code, but that was my first thought.

Comment: @Robert thank you for commenting, based on the  Documentation tha name of it is `GenerateUrl` and with the method above i should get the contents of the  `<value>` tag

Comment: @"Phill Alexakis" Ahh I see, the sentence "I'm trying to Dynamically get the Value of an Attribute from the XML file." threw me off a bit and I was only looking for where you would extract xml attributes. I might be the only one, or I might not be, to get confused by it but it might be a good Idea to clarify that it is the 'Value' element that you want the value of. Sorry I could not be of any help, I hope you'll find a solution.

Comment: Alrigt, i edited the post. I Also  tried adding `<Attribute type="string" length="60" name="GenerateUrl" id="GenerateUrl">GenerateUrl</Attribute>` and i'm still getting a `NullPointerException`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to try another way and do proper parsing of the **XML**

> **If you can use external libs here is how:**

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {
        File stocks = new File("PhillPlugin.xml");
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = dBuilder.parse(stocks);
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

            NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("AttributeValuePair");

            for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
              Node node = nodes.item(i);
              if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                Element element = (Element) node;
                if(i==0)
                 {
                 tempurlGen=getValue("value",element);
                   System.out.println("GenerateUrl: " + getValue("value", element));
                 }
                 else if (i==1)
                 {
                 tempurlVal=getValue("value",element);
                 System.out.println("ValidateUrl: " + getValue("value", element));
                 }

              }
            }
          }
          static String getValue(String tag, Element element) {
            NodeList nodes = element.getElementsByTagName(tag).item(0).getChildNodes();
            Node node = (Node) nodes.item(0);
            return node.getNodeValue();
          }
```

> If you can't include `javax` libraries here is how to parse the `XML` using streams

```java
    public void getXMLData() throws Exception {
        File stocks = new File("PhillPlugin.xml");
        BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(stocks));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int cp;
        while ((cp = in.read()) != -1) {
            sb.append((char) cp);
            String t = sb.toString();
            if (t.contains("</AttributeValuePair>")) {
                String test = sb.toString();
                String test1p[] = test.split("<value>|</value>");
                tempurlGen = test1p[1];
                break;
            }
        }

        sb = new StringBuilder();
        while ((cp = in.read()) != -1) {

            sb.append((char) cp);
            String t = sb.toString();
            if (t.contains("</AttributeValuePair>")) {
                String test = sb.toString();
                String test1p[] = test.split("<value>|</value>");
                tempurlVal = test1p[1];
                break;
            }

        }
    }
```

**Make sure** you define `tempurlGen` and `tempurlVal`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "author",
    "email",
    "creationDate",
    "description",
    "configuration"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "Plugin")
public class Plugin {

    //Add getters and setters including ones for inner classes

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    private String author;
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    private String email;
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    private String creationDate;
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    private String description;
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    private Plugin.Configuration configuration;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "type")
    private String type;

    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
        "attributeValuePair"
    })
    public static class Configuration {

        @XmlElement(name = "AttributeValuePair", required = true)
        private Plugin.Configuration.AttributeValuePair attributeValuePair;

        @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
        @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
            "attribute",
            "mandatory",
            "instanceOverride",
            "globalUIOverride",
            "value"
        })
        public static class AttributeValuePair {

            @XmlElement(name = "Attribute", required = true)
            private Plugin.Configuration.AttributeValuePair.Attribute attribute;
            @XmlElement(required = true)
            private String mandatory;
            @XmlElement(required = true)
            private String instanceOverride;
            @XmlElement(required = true)
            private String globalUIOverride;
            @XmlElement(required = true)
            private String value;

            @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
            @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
                "value"
            })
            public static class Attribute {

                @XmlValue
                private String value;
                @XmlAttribute(name = "type")
                private String type;
                @XmlAttribute(name = "length")
                private Byte length;

            }

        }

    }

}
```

And for the unmarshaling part:

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Plugin.class);
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
StringReader reader = new StringReader("xml string here");
Plugin plugin = (Plugin) unmarshaller.unmarshal(reader);
```

Comment: Thank you , this could possible work, but remember an XML needs to be constructed becuase it is being accessed `OnUpload` by the server